# Calling Controller.notFound() goes through onHandlerNotFound but doesn't take in account the result

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play! framework 2.0.4, I'm running through an issue with the 404 status code handling.
In `Global.java`, I'm overriding `onHandlerNotFound` to return a custom template:

```
@Override
public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader header) {
   return Controller.notFound(views.html.not_found.render());
}
```

It works well for unknown routes but if I call `Controller.notFound()` from a request, it doesn't return anything.

I've tried to debug a bit deeply and it goes through the controller method and then through `onHandlerNotFound` so it should return the right `Result`.

So my question is, is it the correct behavior? If so, how to cleanly redirect every `notFound()` statements to the correct template apart from repeating the previous code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Controller.notFound()` returns basically a HTML 404 response-Object (like `new Object()`). It sets the header for you and probably some other stuff. (It's javadoc says: "Generates a 404 NOT_FOUND simple result")

Whereas the `Global.onHandlerNotFound()` is more like a `try {} catch(HandlerNotFoundException() {}`.

If you call `Controller.notFound()`, you should know what you do. And you can pass it even some Content to display again on the page. (What you do in your `onHandlerNotFound`).

If you really want to execute `Global.onHandlerNotFound`, why not just call it? Otherwise if you usually don't call `Controller.notFound()` but just `notFound()` in `YourController` you can also overwrite this method and call `Global.onHandlerNotFound()`.

To answer your question explicitly, yes it is the correct behavior. These are two different things.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to know if there is an alternative I didn't know about